# Show that every continuous functions on closed interval is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

If $0\notin [a,b]$ show that every continuous function $f$ on [a,b] is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials $q_n$ where $q_n = x^n p_n{(x)}$  for some polynomials $p_n$.

Attempt so far: 
I have to show that $|f - q_n| < \epsilon$  it would not be that hard to show just by using stone-weierstrass theorem but what confused me is $q_n = x^n p_n (x)$.

I appreciate all the helps!

Answer (score 3):

For each $n$, the function $f_n(t)=f(t)t^{-n}$ is continuous. Hence you can approximate it uniformly by a polynomial, $p_n$ given any $\varepsilon >0$. You must approximate it appropriately so that $t^np_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, i.e. you want that $\lVert t^np_n-f\rVert_\infty\to 0$.

*Spoiler*

> Suppose first that $a>0$, and suppose we've taken $\varepsilon_n >0$ and $p_n$ for which $$\sup\limits_{t\in [a,b]}|t^{-n}f(t)-p_n(t)|\leqslant \varepsilon_n$$
>
> Now we have $$\begin{align}\sup\limits_{t\in [a,b]}| f(t)-t^np_n(t)|&=\sup\limits_{t\in [a,b]}|t^n||t^{-n} f(t)-p_n(t)|\\&\leqslant b^n\varepsilon_n\end{align}$$
> So it suffices we arrange it so that $b^n\varepsilon_n\to 0$, for example we may take $\varepsilon_n\leqslant 1/(2b)^n$. For $[a,b]$ to the left of $0$ we must look at $a$ instead of $b$.